# Where and how should I submit a math paper?

Tags: soft-question, advice, publishing

I've been working on a math paper on and off for years and I think I'm about ready to submit it to some Journal. I recently read that LaTex is preferred but I've already done $15$ pages with many equations and exhibits in MS Word. I think it looks pretty good but I don't know. Here is a screen shot of my Abstract. How do I get peer review? Where would you suggest I submit? and do I have to re-do everything in LaTex?

[image]

I can do LaTex if I must but how would I be able to use it on a MacBook Pro with OSX Mojave? On that platform is it a separate editor like TextEdit, Word, or BBEdit?

Comment: Typesetting it in $\LaTeX$ is probably a good idea.

Comment: Whether or not LaTeX is preferred (or even required) or MS-Word is accepted *may* depend on the journal

Comment: 'I think it looks pretty good' means nothing. Each journal will have a _specific_ format that the paper is required to be presented in.

Comment: If you have no experience with LaTeX, aren't interested in breaking your teeth on it now, and can afford it, you may want to think about hiring someone to typeset it for you.

Comment: As Mattos notes, each journal has specific submission guidelines; these are typically available online. Some publications accept MSWord, but almost-certainly that means someone there will have to translate it into $\LaTeX$. (It's not like someone's just going to copy your text and paste it into a journal. It needs to be formatted to match the layout style, etc., and this is easily done by fiddling with TeX parameters.) You may be better off reducing friction by TeXing things up yourself. As for editing $\LaTeX$ on a Mac, I use [TeXShop](https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/obtaining.html).

Comment: @BallBoy I have used LaTeX here so I just need to know how it will interface with what I am using or if it is a standalone application for download.

Comment: @Blue This array works in MSE and LaTeXiT but yields: "Undefined Control Sequence" in TeXShop for the line following \begin.... Any ideas?

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|} 
\text{$Set_n$} & \text{$Triple_1$} & \text{$Triple_2$} & \text{$Triple_3$} & \text{$Triple_4$}\\ \hline
\text{$Set_1$} & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13 & 7,24,25& 9,40,41\\ \hline
\text{$Set_2$} & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 & 27,36,45 &33,56,65\\ \hline
\text{$Set_3$} & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 & 55,48,73 &65,72,97 \\ \hline
\text{$Set_4$} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 & 91,60,109 &105,88,137\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: @poetasis: Keep in mind that MathJax only *approximates* TeX, so expect hiccups. ... I created a new TeXShop doc, pasted in your text. I got a "Missing `$` inserted" error, because I forgot to wrap the array stuff with `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` (don't use `$$...$$`). Since you didn't get that, you must be doing okay there. ... After I fixed that, TeXShop gave me an "Undefined Control Sequence" error. It didn't like `\text{}`. Rather, my chosen document class (`article`) didn't like it. Switching to `amsart` (which is a better default, anyway) allowed the array to render. Try that.

Comment: @poetasis: By the way, you don't want `\text{$Set_n$}`. Instead, use `\text{Set}_n`. For one thing, by wrapping `Set_n` in `$...$`, you've set it to render in mathmode, nullifying the `\text{}` operator altogether. :) But also, you only want the word `Set` to be text; the subscript is a mathmode thing, so leave it outside the `\text{}` group. ... I'll use this remaining space in this comment to note that the dedicated [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com) is invaluable for getting past hiccups, learning which packages to load to get special functionality, etc.

Comment: @Blue You've been extremely helpful to a TeXShop newbie. I figured out that I don't even what to put the \text in front of Set_n because it stands alone and even subscripts without the \$s.

Comment: What does "there is a Pythagorean triple for every pair of natural numbers" mean? (If $(a,b,c)$ is a Pythagorean triple and $(n,m)$ is a pair of natural numbers what does it mean to say $(a,b,c)$ is "for" $(n,m)$?)

Comment: $$ \forall n,k\in\mathbb{N},\exists A,B,C\in\mathbb{N}:A^2+B^2=C^2$$

Comment: How does the above statement depend on $n,k$? I fix $n,k$ and $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$ is trivially satisfied.

Comment: $$A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\qquad B=2(2n-1)k+2k^2\qquad C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2 $$
It is equivalent to replacing $m,n$ by $2m-1+n,n$ and it generates no trivial triples.

Comment: Thanks to all of you who have been so helpful. In the last 24 hours, I've re-platformed $10$ of $15$ pages from Word to TeXShop.

Comment: @Alvin Lepik Did you get something other than $(45,28,53)$?

Comment: @poetasis miscalculated and thought I found a counter-example. Ran the numbers again and indeed $A^2 + B^2 = C^2$ does always hold. Well done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which journal is right for the paper depends upon the sub-discipline (apparently number theory, or possibly geometry), and the level.  Go to the [American Mathematical Society Journals page](https://www.ams.org/journals) for guidance.

[$\LaTeX$ is strongly advised](http://tex.loria.fr/general/mil.pdf).  *MS Word* is hopeless for truly sophisticated math typesetting.